# Unable to install package using dpkg

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome, dpkg

I'm trying to install chrome on ubuntu 14.04. Mine is a 64 bit system.
I'm getting this error.

```
$ sudo dpkg –i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
dpkg: error: need an action option`

`Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;`

`Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more'!`
```

As far as I understand, -i is an action option. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you copy-pasted the command and it contains non-ASCII characters (the `–` is not a `-` for example), try actually typing it.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks. That worked. But now I'm getting a new error. `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on libappindicator1; however:

dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
`

Comment: @ak31 told you not to use `dpkg` unless you needed to. Now do `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm going to guess that is a command you copied from a website or something like that, because that dash in front of the `i` is not a hyphen (or minus), but an [en-dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm):

```
$ od -c <<<"–"
0000000 342 200 223  \n
0000004
$ od -c <<<"-"
0000000   -  \n
0000002
```

Use a proper `-` instead.

And don't use `dpkg` unless you need to; the Software Centre can handle `.deb` files just fine, just double click on the file, or do `xdg-open google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`.

Comment: em-dash!  Annoy your friends and families!  Thanks.

Comment: @Zanna interesting, thanks! That's one part of the 10k tools I haven't looked at much.